# Convert an hexadecimal number to a string

Tags: php, string, hex

I'm trying to convert an hexadecimal number into correct `css` formating:

```
$white = hexdec('#ffffff');

//Loops for a bunch of colours
for( $i = 0 ; $i <= $white ; $i=$i+5000 ) 
{
    //set default css background-color property
    $backgroundValue = dechex( $i );

    //if there are less of 7 characters (ex. #fa444, or #32F, ...)  
    if( $numLen = strlen( dechex( $i )) < 7 ) 
    {
        //insert (7 - numbers of characters) number of zeros after # 
        for ( $j = 0 ; $j < 7 - $numLen ; $j++ )
            $backgroundValue = strtr( $backgroundValue, '#', '#0' );                
    }
    //echo each div with each background-color property. 
    echo '<div class="colour" style="width: 10%; float: left; background: '.$backgroundValue.';">'.dechex($i).'</div>';
}
```

But this doesn't work. How could I turn the hexadecimal number into a string like: `#FFFFFF` .

**Update:**

The problem was that I wasn't passing the `#` to the start of the string: `$backgroundValue = '#'.dechex( $i );`.

This code is working fine:

```
        $white = hexdec('#ffffff');
        for( $i = 0 ; $i <= $white ; $i=$i+10000 ) 
        {
            $backgroundValue = '#'.dechex( $i );
            $numLen = strlen( dechex( $i ));

            if( $numLen < 6 ) 
            {

                for ( $j = 0 ; $j < (6 - $numLen) ; $j++ )
                    $backgroundValue = str_replace( '#', '#0', $backgroundValue );              
            }

            echo '<div class="colour" style="width: 10%; float: left; background: '.$backgroundValue.';">'.$backgroundValue.'</div>';
        }
```

Comment: This link might help: http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_convert_rgb_from_to_html_hex_color.xml

Comment: `$white = hexdec('ffffff'); // <-- 16777215
var_dump(dechex($white)); // <-- 'ffffff'`

Comment: You were missing a `)` for the `strtr()` function and the `#` for the colour property, but it works for me? http://jsfiddle.net/fxm79/ http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/efb1e4c7a9cd44e8009f544c323b8009adb211e1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use `str_repeat`?

```
$end = 0xffffff;

for ($i = 0; $i < $end; $i += 5000) {
    $color = (string) dechex($i);
    $backgroundValue = '#' . str_repeat('0', 6 - strlen($color)) . $color;
    echo '<div class="colour" style="width: 10%; float: left; background: '.$backgroundValue.';">'.dechex($i).'</div>';
}
```

you could also use sprintf

```
$backgroundValue = sprintf('#%06x', $i);
```

Comment: why use `str_repeat` when there is `str_pad` function? `'#'.str_pad(dechex($i), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT)`

Comment: attention: your str_repeat is wrong! `ffff00 = 16776960`, `00ffff or ffff = 65535`

Comment: `$backgroundValue` is not correct. Please, change with: `$backgroundValue = '#' . str_repeat('0', 6 - strlen($color)) . $color;`

Comment: sorry - i got this wrong. added a way shorter version with `sprintf`